# DNS resolution issue in Ubuntu VM when NOT connected through proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, dns, virtual-machine

So I'm on a work laptop whose internet connection goes through the company proxy server by default. When I disconnect from the proxy and access the internet directly, my laptop accesses the internet without a problem, but my Ubuntu VM (running in VirtualBox, with Windows 10 as the host OS) has no internet access and is unable to resolve the IP address of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

I'm guessing I was behind the proxy when I set up the VM, but I just want to know how to fix this (without having to make a new VM). I tried restarting the VM with "Bridged" networking instead of "NAT" networking, but that did no good.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround (see below). Only downside is that DNS resolution becomes slow when I resume using the proxy, but that is fixed by reverting the change.

sudo apt-get install && sudo apt-get install resolvconf
sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
Add the following lines:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
sudo resolvconf -u
sudo service resolvconf restart